# What type of HTTP redirect for "page=1" to non-"page=1" URL

Tags: rest, redirect

I would like to redirect all `http://example.com/searchresults?page=1` to `http://example.com/searchresults`

As you can guess, the page is search results, the get parameter for paging is `page` but specifically i do not want `?page=1` versions to exist. if page is 1, i want to redirect to the non-"page" version (my code handles that, if no page is set, it assumes page=1).

**What is the proper type of HTTP redirect i should use in `?page=1` requests?**

Currently i'm using "301 moved permanently" but i'm not sure if i need to change this to "303 see other"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `301 Moved Permanently`, since you're returning an equivalent URI for the exact same resource.

`303 See Other` is used when you return an URI for another resource that's not the same as the one at the original URI, but can fulfill the request indirectly.

By the way, REST is protocol independent. These are HTTP redirects, not REST redirects.